# Why the Minimax Principle says that $\nu_n$ is given by minimizing the same expression as for $\mu_n$ over a larger space

Tags: inequalities, convex-optimization

From the article [Weyl's law](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~stevmatt/weyl_law.pdf) of Matt Stevenson page $3$, there's a lemma where I'd like some help to understand the proof.

> **Lemma.** Let $\mu_n$ be the Dirichlet eigenvalues on $\Omega$ and $\nu_n$ be the Neumann eigenvalues on $\Omega$, then $\nu_n \leq
>  \mu_n$.
>
> *Pf :* Remark that $H_0^1 (\Omega) \subset H^1 (\Omega)$, so $\Phi(H_0^1 (\Omega)) \subset \Phi(H^1 (\Omega)).$ Then, version $2$
>   of the Minimax Principle says that $\nu_n$ is given by minimizing the
>   same expression as for $\mu_n$ over a larger space, and hence $\nu_n
>  \leq \mu_n$.

**Question :** Could anyone be able to explain to me with clear words, rigorously,  why the Minimax Principle says that $\nu_n$ is given by minimizing the same expression (i.e. $ \inf_{X \in \Phi_n(V)} \sup_{u \in X} \frac{\|\nabla u(\Omega)\|^2}{\|u(\Omega)\|^2}$) as for $\mu_n$ over a larger space ?

Comment: Is it too much to ask that you stick to using one user account on MO, especially since some of them are still open/unsuspended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save my fingers some typing, denote by $\mathcal{R}$ the Rayleigh quotient, $\mathcal{R}(u) = \|\nabla u\|^2/\|u\|^2$. Let 
$$R(H) = \{\sup_{u\in X^n}\mathcal{R}(u)\ |\ X\in\Phi(H)\}$$
where $H\in \{H^1_0,H^1\}$. Notice that $R$ is the image of a function $\Phi(H)\to\mathbb{R}$ taking $X\mapsto\sup_{u\in X}\mathcal{R}(u)$.  As $\Phi(H^1_0)\subset\Phi(H^1)$, we have that $R(H^1_0)\subseteq R(H^1)$. That $\mu_n\geq\nu_n$ follows from taking infima.

Comment: I had already know that if $A \subset B \subset \mathbb{R}$, then $\inf(A) \geq \inf(B)$. I should have been more specific in my question. Could you explain why $R(H^1_0)\subseteq R(H^1)$?

Comment: @CHSLD is that clearer?

Comment: Yes, It is understandable now.

Comment: This question is for you : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1891353/domain-monotonicity-mu-n-omega-2-leq-mu-n-omega-1. This is a similar question to that one, and I used your hint. I wanted to know if I am right.